# Two different WordPress hooks with the same callback

Tags: php, wordpress

I made a plugin that converts any uri to a hyperlink, if it finds hyper-link it will ignore it and only convert the no hyper-links uri.
In the plugin admin page I set two options, first to convert links only for the front-end, and the second option is to convert uri when ever a post/comment saved to database.

```
// permanently means before save to database
if ( $this->plugin_options['uri2links_convert_method'] == 'permanently' ) {
    add_action( 'wp_insert_post_data', array($this, 'make_post_url_clickable' ) );
        //add_action( 'preprocess_comment', array($this, 'make_comment_url_clickable' ) );
}
else {
    add_filter( 'the_content', array($this, 'make_post_url_clickable' ) );
    //add_filter( 'preprocess_comment', array($this, 'make_comment_url_clickable' ) );
}
```

My problem here if I set the plugin option to convert uri for front-end it will ignore hyper-links and convert the other uri, but if I set it to convert before save to database it 'll not ignore hyper-links and treat them as normal uri witch make the results look like this:

```
<a class="sdf" href=" <a href="http://test.test-75.1474.stackoverflow.com/" >http://test.test-75.1474.stackoverflow.com/</a> " target="_blank" rel=" <a href="http://127.0.0.1/wplu" >http://127.0.0.1/wplu</a> "> <a href="http://test.test-75.1474.stackoverflow.com/" >http://test.test-75.1474.stackoverflow.com/</a> </a>
<a class="sdf" href=" <a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com" >https://www.stackoverflow.com</a> " target="_blank" rel=" <a href="http://127.0.0.1/wplu" >http://127.0.0.1/wplu</a> "> <a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com" >https://www.stackoverflow.com</a> </a>
```

The complete plugin source code:

```
<?php
  /*
    Plugin name: URIs to a click-able links
    Plugin URI:
    Description: Convert URI's to a click-able links
    Author: h Abdou
    Author URI: habdou.me
    Version: 1.0
  */

  // The admin page for the plugin
  require_once( 'uri2links-menu.php' );

  class Uri2Links {

    protected $css                 = '';
    protected $rel                 = '';
    protected $target              = '';
    protected $convert_links       = '';
    protected $convert_emails      = '';
    protected $plugin_options      = array();
    protected $url_match_pattern   = '/[a-zA-Z0-9\.\/\?\:@\-_=#]+\.([a-zA-Z0-9\.\/\?\:@\-_=#])+/';
    protected $email_match_pattern = '/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$/';
    //protected $links_match_pattern = '/<a(?:"[^"]*"[\'"]*|\'[^\']*\'[\'"]*|[^\'">])+>^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$<\/a>/';
    protected $links_match_pattern = '/<a[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a>/';
    protected $links_matched       = array();

    public function __construct() {
      //$this->plugin_options = get_option( 'uri2links_plugin_options' );
      $this->plugin_options = array( 'uri2links_convertLinksEmails' => array( 'Links', 'Emails' ), 'uri2links_convert_method' => 'permanently' );
      $this->css            = isset( $this->plugin_options['uri2links_custom_css'] ) ? ' class="' . $this->plugin_options['uri2links_custom_css']  . '"' : '';
      $this->rel            = isset( $this->plugin_options['uri2links_rel_attr'] ) ? ' rel="' . $this->plugin_options['uri2links_rel_attr']  . '"' : '';
      if ( isset( $this->plugin_options['uri2links_open_links_method'] ) && $this->plugin_options['uri2links_open_links_method'] == 'new')
        $this->target = ' target="_blank"';

      $this->convert_links  = isset( $this->plugin_options['uri2links_convertLinksEmails'][0] ) ? $this->plugin_options['uri2links_convertLinksEmails'][0] : '';
      $this->convert_emails = isset( $this->plugin_options['uri2links_convertLinksEmails'][1] ) ? $this->plugin_options['uri2links_convertLinksEmails'][1] : '';
      if ( $this->plugin_options['uri2links_convert_method'] == 'permanently' ) {
        add_action( 'wp_insert_post_data', array($this, 'make_post_url_clickable' ) );
        //add_action( 'preprocess_comment', array($this, 'make_comment_url_clickable' ) );
      }
      else {
        add_filter( 'the_content', array($this, 'make_post_url_clickable' ) );
        //add_filter( 'preprocess_comment', array($this, 'make_comment_url_clickable' ) );
      }

      // The admin page for the plugin
      new Uri2LinksMenu;
    }

    // Convert all URI in a post to hyper-links.
    public function make_post_url_clickable( $content ) {
      $links = $this->hash_links( $content );
      if ( $this->convert_links == 'Links' ) {
        $content =  preg_replace($this->url_match_pattern, ' <a href="\\0"' . $this->css . $this->rel . $this->target . ' >\\0</a> ', $content);
      }

      if ( $this->convert_emails == 'Emails' ) {
        $content =  preg_replace($this->email_match_pattern, ' <a href="mailto:\\0"' . $this->css . $this->rel . $this->target . ' >\\0</a> ', $content);
      }

      // Replace back the hashed 'a' tags to the original status.
      foreach ( $links as $link_hash => $link_text ) {
        $content = str_replace( $link_hash, $link_text, $content );
      }

      return $content;
    }

    // Same as 'make_post_url_clickable' but this for comments
    public function make_comment_url_clickable( $content ) {
      $links = hash_links( $content['comment_content']['comment_content'] );
      if ( $this->convert_links == 'Links' ) {
        $content['comment_content'] =  preg_replace($this->url_match_pattern, ' <a href="\\0"' . $this->css . $this->rel . $this->target . ' >\\0</a> ', $content['comment_content']);
      }

      if ( $this->convert_emails == 'Emails' ) {
        $content['comment_content'] =  preg_replace($this->email_match_pattern, ' <a href="mailto:\\0"' . $this->css . $this->rel . $this->target . ' >\\0</a> ', $content['comment_content']);
      }

      foreach ( $links as $link_hash => $link_text ) {
        $content['comment_content'] = str_replace( $link_hash, $link_text, $content['comment_content'] );
      }

      return $content;
    }

    // hash all 'a' tags so 'make_*_url_clickable' will ignore them.
    public function hash_links( &$content ) {
      $links = array();
      if ( preg_match_all( $this->links_match_pattern, $content, $matches ) ) {
        $array_size = sizeof( $matches[0] );
        for ( $i = 0; $i < $array_size; ++$i ) {
          $link_hash = md5( $matches[0][$i] );
          $links[$link_hash] = $matches[0][$i];
          $content = str_replace( $matches[0][$i], $link_hash, $content );
        }
      }

      //die('hash_links called!');
      return $links;
    }

  }

  new Uri2Links;
?>
```

Comment: How does it skip the existing hyperlinks? Can you for example run it twice through the `the_content` filter to test if it skips hyperlinks? I think it would be easier to test if you would extract it into a single test function with some predefined text, instead of running it through WordPress.

Comment: @birgire First tested those functions in a separate file and they work well, the problem only appears when I use `wp_insert_post_data` hook. Also using the_content hook in both cases work fine but again, if I use `wp_insert_post_data` hook the problems start again.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to mention that WordPress already got the `make_clickable()` function that takes text uri to HTML links.

To activate it for the post content we only need this simple plugin:

```
<?php 
/** Plugin Name: Make text uri to HTML links in the post content **/

add_filter( 'the_content', 'make_clickable', 9 );
```

By default this function runs on the comment text:

```
add_filter( 'comment_text', 'make_clickable', 9 );
```

Comment: `make_clickable` works fine but in my case I want to convert URI then save to the database. I am still see problems with `` hook even if I use it with `make_clickable`.